# How to initialize numbers variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm following some Javascript good practices and I have a doubt about how to initialize numbers.

Reading some articles I found those examples of variable initialization:

```
var name = '';
var price = 0;
var car = {};
```

The problem: I have a variable called productCode where I will store a number witch 5 characters Ex.: 22738.
Each productCode represents a product like:

Code: 11234 Product: T-Shit

Code: 12344 Product: Shoes

Should I initizlize productCode variable with zero or what?

Thank you.

Comment: Initialize it to whatever value makes sense in your program. We can't know if you don't explain why you want to initialize variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the variable to `0`, assuming there is no use case where the user code could ever be `0`. This way, the data remains consistent.

If you were to put the code into a function, the function would consistently return a number, instead of potentially returning `undefined` sometimes.

Initialization to a consistent type keeps later conditions and code cleaner that interact with the variable.

w3schools has a [list of best practices](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_best_practices.asp) published for JavaScript, which touches upon variable initialization.

Comment: Corrected it to say "number", which was the point I was trying to convey, not the variable type.

Comment: Why 0 instead of -0, -1, 1234, Infinity or NaN?

Comment: -1 is usually associated with errors, 1234 could be a real user ID, NaN is inconsistent with what you expect the data type to be (it IS a number..), and Infinity evaluates to true if you were to do `if(user_code)`.

But most importantly, 0 is the most common initialization for a variable that one expects to be an integer, and thus, the most readable.

Comment: What makes you think OP's IDs are finite strictly-positive integers? And note NaN is a number, despite its name.

Comment: With the limited information in the post, I am interpreting the number to be a positive integer that identifies a user. He doesn't specify what user code actually means, hence the complaints of ambiguity you are seeing from others.

Comment: NaN causes cognitive dissonance, because it indicates that a variable is not a number. Just because you can technically initialize it to all of these suggestions, doesn't mean you should.

Comment: Why not `null` (or `undefined`) to represent a *no-value-yet* state?! "No value" and "a value of 0" can specifically be distinguished through that.

Comment: It depends on the context though, and what "user code" actually means I suppose. You have a really good point there.

Answer (score 0):

If the user code is always number, you can initialize it like a number if the code is less than 2^53, which it most likely will be.
But considering that Javascript is a weakly typed language, you don't have to initialize it at all, because the data type will be derived from the assigned value. If you initialize it with any value, you will however not make any mistake.

Comment: Why will 0 never be a mistake?

Comment: Since he wants to assign numbers to the variable I suppose initializing it with a zero is harmless.

Comment: If the initial value is not used by latter code, all values are harmeless. Otherwise, we can't know whether zero is harmless or not.

Comment: I have changed the answer, the zero is truly misleading.

Answer (score -1):

No need to initialize it. You can store any type in a single variable anyway:

```
var v;
v = 1;
v = "a";
v = true;
// etc...
```

Comment: How will JavaScript engine work if a variable is declared it as an `undefined` and later in the lifecycle of the program, it is being _varied_ as `Number` or `String` or any other data type.. OP is asking about better practices which may include `readability` as well.. By the way  I'm not among the downvotes..

Comment: @RayonDabre Thanks, I understand and I agree with your point of view. Though, I'm not able to guess so many things from such a poorly detailed question (there is nothing about readability for example) :-P

Comment: OP expects you to _guess them coorectly_ for the sake of doubt clarification.. ;)

Comment: Agreed.. Initializing it to `0` would make more sense.

Comment: @RayonDabre Why 0? The "natural" initial value (if any) depends on the context, which the OP doesn't provide.

Comment: Moreover, why `0` since you are not going to use such a value anyway?

Comment: As mentioned in the post, what he meant was if the value is about to be changed in the future and it will be  Number for sure then How it should be Declared. And in that case, initializing it to `0` would make code more readable. Correct me sir If am wrong..

Comment: @RayonDabre It would make sense if you had to apply ++ or -- for example. It doesn't seem to be the case since it's about user ids. Then I don't think it would make the program easier to understand. You have many powerful ways to make a program readable in place of initializing with useless values :-/